# Bridge or factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory, bridge

In my design, at the first time, I was designing a factory pattern. But one person recommend use better the bridge pattern.

This is my scenario: [How to improve my abstract factory pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917911/how-to-improve-my-abstract-factory-pattern)

I just want to know which pattern is the best for this scenario.. I'm getting confused!

A summary of my scenario is:

> Imagine a black box, this black box receives a object called
>   `Configuration` and it output is a `Problem` object
>
> This black box at the beginning I was calling a factory, but later I
>   need to use generics to be more specific in my abstract class and so,
>   one person told better use the bridge.
>
> Also, in my factory, needs to receive the input value in the
>   constructor, and also can modify the instance.. so this part is the
>   cruxial.

I don't kow very much that pattern, so I just want using this brief scenario, what shoud I do?

Comment: Could you please post a summary of *this scenario*?

Comment: @oleksii of course, let me added!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a bridge. It's used to have one interface where multiple implementations can be used. This allows for switching of implementations without the user knowing about it.
You want to use the both the problem and configuration factory's next to each other.

If you would want to switch between using the problem and configuration sections without the user knowing, then you would use the bridge.

Please remember you can use as many patterns at the same time as you want, also in this situations you are not forced to choose between. Use what you think is most effective.

Comment: More to the point...don't worry about solving the problem *using pattern X*.  Just solve the problem.  If pattern X is the natural solution, it will appear anyway (in one form or another).

Comment: @cHao I really like so much this last comment. I guess sometimes I complicated because I'm looking for the right pattern, but as you say, the patterns appears by nature!

Answer (score 2):

Technically it doesn't really matter here and I don't think your architecture would benefit from switching to the bridge. Here's why:

Bridge is useful when your hierarchy has **two** different degrees of freedom - it seems that yours have: first is problem and second is configuration.

In bridge, you'd extract one hierarchy away and inject it into the other. So for example you have an abstract class `Problem` with its own hierarchy (`ProblemA`, `VeryDifficultProblem`) and you inject an implementation from the other hierarchy (`ConcreteConfiguration1` etc.)

What's crucial here are two **hierarchies**. If your problem doesn't form class hierarchies but rather you'd like to specify contracts with interfaces (so that implementing classes could come from different subtrees of the hierarchy), then Bridge would be unnatural and I would stick with the Factory. And I don't think Bridge has much sense when implementing it with interfaces rather than abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parametrized factory pattern, I am not sure Bridge is designed to solve your problem.

```
interface IFactory<TConfiguration,TProblem> 
          where TProblem: IProblem
          where TConfiguration: IConfiguration
{
   TProblem Create(TConfiguration config);
}

class Factory<TConfiguration,TProblem>: IFactory<TConfiguration,TProblem>
          where TProblem: IProblem
          where TConfiguration: IConfiguration
{
   TProblem Create(TConfiguration config)
   {
       var problem = new Problem(config);
       ...
       return problem;
   }
}
```

<sub>NB code written in notepad so may not compile, but I hope the idea is clear</sub>

Comment: I was thinking in that way at the beginning. I doubted because my interface is generic and I've seen many classes like this but as the lowest class is a non generic class. So this doesn't matter?